# AWS RDS SQL Server Backup Restore Issue

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have setup the RDS instance for SQL Server 2019 SE. Option group also created with major version=15. SQL Server backup and restore option is added along with S3 settings and IAM role. The option group is also attached with instance.

I executed the command;

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='MyDatabaseOnRDS_Staging', 
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName/MyDatabaseOnRDS_Staging.bak';
```

The above statement created the task which is visible in;

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;
```

The % complete goes to 100%. But then it shows ERROR in 'lifecycle' column. When I check the details in task_info column, it shows the error at the end;

> The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database.  Changed database context to 'master'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue was sa user. It was added as a db user. It was in disabled state, but for some reason AWS RDS was not allowing rdsa to be the DB owner of the DB in restore as sa was the part of db users.

I did to following steps;

1. Changed the sa schema owner to dbo
2. Removed sa user (just user and not the sa schema) from the DB Users.
3. Took the backup, copied the backup to S3 and restored it.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to restore the database from within a connection to that database. Change the context you're executing the restore operation from to the master database, as the error suggested.

Comment: The database selected in SSMS is master. And there is just one rdsadmin db on the instance.